# How can I get user input in a specific format using scanf?

Tags: c, string, scanf

Let's assume that I want to get a user input in this form and each line will be defined to my different structure objects.
Input format of my input.txt file:

```
3 // number of lines
1 2 3 (4/5) 6 7
34 58 6 (23/12) 442 12
14 85 13 (43/12) 98 67
```

I want to assign each integer from 1 to 7 to my objects values which are defined in a structure let's say.

I tried scanf like this, but doesn't seem to work;

```
for (int i=0;i<3;i++)
    scanf("%d %d %d (%d/%d) %d %d", &a,&b,&c,&d,&e,&f,&g);
```

Comment: You are using `scanf()` so I presume you are redirecting the text file. Where do you read the `3` which is hard coded? When put in a proper program, and the hard-coded `3` is read from file too, the code works.

Comment: Read all lines with `fgets()` into an adequately sized buffer (character array) and then use `sscanf()` to separate the values ***checking the return*** to determine if a successful conversion took place.

Comment: You need to check the return of `scanf`, it returns the number of parameters that were successfully read according to the format string specified. In this example `scanf` should return 7 when all 7 integer numbers are correctly read in the input.

Comment: Voted to close because the code fragment isn't enough to show where it is going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with the snippets you have shown other than a failure to check the return for `scanf()`. A better approach would be to read each line into a sufficiently sized character array and then separate the integers using `sscanf()` so that you consume a line of input each time.

Otherwise, using `scanf()` if there is a single format failure in the file, your input is corrupted from the point of the *matching-failure* on. Using `fgets()` and then `sscanf()` you decouple the read and conversion so at most a format failure in a single line only results in the loss of that line's data. What remains in your input stream isn't dependent on the conversion.

A short example addressing the issue would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXC 1024       /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */

typedef struct {                        /* guess at your struct */
    int i1, i2, i3, i4, i5, i6, i7;
} numbers;

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    
    char buf[MAXC];                     /* buffer to hold each line */
    int n = 0, nlines;                  /* counter and 1st line variable */
    numbers no = { .i1 = 0 };           /* struct initialized all zero */
    /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }
    
    if (!fgets (buf, MAXC, fp))                 /* read 1st line */
        return 1;
    if (sscanf (buf, "%d", &nlines) != 1) {     /* convert/validate nlines */
        fputs ("error: invalid 1st line format.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    /* read each line that follows up to nlines */
    while (n < nlines && fgets (buf, MAXC, fp)) { 
        /* convert & validate each integer saving in struct */
        if (sscanf (buf, "%d %d %d (%d /%d ) %d %d", &no.i1, &no.i2, &no.i3,
                    &no.i4, &no.i5, &no.i6, &no.i7) == 7)
            /* output results */
            printf ("\nstruct values:\n%4d %4d %4d %4d %4d %4d %4d\n",
                    no.i1, no.i2, no.i3, no.i4, no.i5, no.i6, no.i7);
        n++;
    }
    
    if (fp != stdin)   /* close file if not stdin */
        fclose (fp);
}
```

**Example Input File**

```
$ cat dat/read7int_struct.txt
3 // number of lines
1 2 3 (4/5) 6 7
34 58 6 (23/12) 442 12
14 85 13 (43/12) 98 67
```

**Example Use/Output**

Reading values redirected on `stdin`:

```
$ ./bin/read7int_struct < dat/read7int_struct.txt

struct values:
   1    2    3    4    5    6    7

struct values:
  34   58    6   23   12  442   12

struct values:
  14   85   13   43   12   98   67
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Aside: `"%d %d %d (%d /%d ) %d %d"` (note space before non-specifier) is more forgiving.

Comment: Always room for improvement. Well played.

Comment: But all the spaces in the format before an instance of `%d` are totally unnecessary.

Comment: Yep, but are perfectly fine and makes for a much more readable format-string for older eyes...